# Create a script file for another programming language from within R (writing a long text with many special characters to a file)

Tags: r

I have an R script that makes a Bash call to execute a `perl` script. However, I need to fit everything into a single `.R` file. Hence, I want to add the `Perl` script into the body of my R code, so that the `.pl` file will be generated from within R.

I have so far tried to do this with `writeLines` but this seems to be very tricky as I cannot simply paste the entire script into one object and have to break it into pieces with `paste`. This is mainly caused by the fact that my `Perl` script contains many `"` and  `'` characters that confuses R.

Is there an easy way to achieve this with the least amount of usage of `paste`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `cat()` function could be of help. If I understand correctly what you want is a R script that will generate a perl script. If so, what you can do is use `cat` like so:

```
cat("piece of script", file = "path/to/script.pl")
```

use `append=T` to keep editing the script:

```
cat("piece of script", file = "path/tp/script.pl", append =T)
```

Then call the script with `system()` (I guess you already know that):

```
system("perl path/to/script.pl")
```

Regarding the quotation marks, I guess you have to deal with them properly in your R script, *i.e*:

```
cat("`piece of script`", file = "path/tp/script.pl", append =T)
```

for single quotation marks and

```
 cat("\"piece of script\"", file = "path/tp/script.pl", append =T)
```

for double.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Too bad I cannot +1 your answer as well as accepting it as the correct answer. But this was a life saver. I absolutely had no idea that escaping characters (using backslash) works inside `cat`. You saved me hours!

Comment: I am glad it helped you!

Comment: @KevinCazelles I'm trying to use your idea to do the same but with a .R file--that is, use an R script to create several R scripts, which naturally have many quotation marks. They're usually double quotation marks, so I tried your "\"solution\"" but it doesn't seem to work. Is that only viable for using R scripts to create perl scripts?